# how to share a repository inside a chroot in a VM with visual studio on windows dev PC?

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, chroot, arm

I have a windows development machine on which I have visual studio, and I have a debian stretch in a virtualbox VM, in which I have a chroot.

I created a chroot to have armhf versions of libraries, which I need to build our software which runs on an embedded (cortex A) ARM platform (we use make, g++ etc). The chroot lives in a folder in my home directory inside the linux VM. I chroot into it (sudo chroot) and then pull my code and build it and then copy it over the network onto the platform.

I'd like to streamline my workflow and share the code folder inside the chroot with the host OS (windows) so I can open the project in visual studio and work on the code there. If possible i'd even like to use VS as the IDE and use the linux build tools/libraries, perhaps so I can even remotely debug the application.

**My question: how do I share the folder inside the chroot with the host OS, windows 10?**

Comment: Basically the VM will have to run samba on the folder you want to share, the host can access it as "shared folder". I don't know the details of how virtualbox implements shared folders, but it may or may not be configurable this way. If it isn't, you must start samba explicitely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the VirtualBox Guest Additions installed, you can use [shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) to mount a directory from the host machine to a mount point inside the VM. Do note that you'll probably want to set this up first before you copy your code over to the new directory.

That said, I am not very confident that Visual Studio will be able to build your product since it and the build tools are for a different platform and architecture, although someone with more knowledge about VS may have a better solution.

Comment: my goal right now is just to edit my code using visual studio because I like that environment. I'll keep using make to build the software for now. I know you can create shared folders between the host OS and the VM, but what I want to do is share an existing folder inside the chroot, with the host OS, and that is not the same thing.

Comment: @b20000 you could do the chroot in the shared folder so the host could access all files in the chroot.

Comment: OK ... doesn't that cause a permissions problem though?

Comment: I don't think so... I'm not positive how the shared folder driver works, but I think permissions don't really apply between host and guest.